# actualización de postgres de manera remota y automática

Tags: php, c#, postgresql

Buenas tardes Srs. de ante mano muchas gracias por cualquier apoyo, esta vez tengo la siguiente duda.

Tengo 2 `BD` una en la nube y la otra en local ambas poseen las mismas
tablas y todo exactamente igual. mi pregunta es: ¿cómo actualizo de
manera automática cada `BD`?. Por ejemplo:  una estación de trabajo esta de
manera local y se le desconecta el Internet por "y" razón, como tengo
una `BD` local puedo seguir trabajando, pero cuando llegue el internet
debería actualizarse automáticamente todos los datos en la nube,
¿por qué? porque con la `BD` en la nube hay una persona viendo los
movimientos de esta estación. Quizás esta estación trabaja hasta las
5:00 pm y el usuario olvidó hacer algún cambio; lo hace desde su casa
y en la mañana, cuando encienda la estación, se actualizará la misma
automáticamente. Espero haberme dado a entender.

estoy usando `postgres 9.4 y c#` en local y `postgres 9.4 y php` de manera online

Answer (score 1):

No hay una manera automática que resuelva todos los problemas. No hay una definición única y universalmente aceptada sobre qué significa actualizar una DB.

Por ejemplo si el usuario que se había desconectado cambia el campo "A"del registro "X" de la tabla "Z", y otro usuario que no estaba desconectado durante el período de desconección del primero cambia el valor del campo "B" del registro "X" de la tabla "Z". ¿Qué se espera? ¿que mezcle las dos actualizaciones? ¿qué ponga la última?

¿y qué pasa si en ese caso se agregaron registros en la tabla "T" que para que sean coherentes dependen de que el valor de "A" en el primer caso o de "B" en el segundo caso estén grabadas? ¿se agregan los de un solo usuario? ¿cuál?

Como se puede ver no es tan simple. Hay que verlo caso por caso.

Comment: primero muchas gracias por tratar de ayudarme.. coloquemos un poco mas simple el caso, una hora en especifico horario de oficina, quiza actualizar de la nube al local a las 8:00 am y de local a la nube a las 5:00 pm se podria asi?

Comment: El problema no cambia con el horario. Las preguntas siguen siendo las mismas. Si pudieras asegurarte que mientras el usuario local estuvo desconectado nadie (absolutamente nadie) cambió nada (absolutamente nada) en la base global se podrían volver a mandar todos los SQL, uno por uno, en orden, que se usaron en la máquina local para actualizar la base de datos.

Comment: pero se podria realizar una función; donde si no hay ningún usuario local activo actualizar la nube tener en base de datos información de la estacion y bitácora por estación.. se podría colocar quizá que se ejecute esa función cada vez que el usuario se desconecte

Comment: Sí. Pero no en forma automática e incondicional. Si la base en la nube fue actualizada, quizás la bitácora de cambios locales pongan a la base de datos en una situación de incoherencia de datos. ¿Qué pasa si localmente se le agregan registros en la tabla hijos y en la nube se borró al futuro padre (que en ese momento no tenía hijos)?

Comment: entonces que seria lo mas apropiado? tengo un software completamente web y cierto cliente lo quiere en local porque tiene mala conexion de internet pero no quiere perder las bondades que le ofrece el sistema web por que el desde el tlf solo revisa los movimientos y en local esta la salida de la mercancía, este usuario no tiene permiso a agregar o modificar solo a descargar por punto de venta, mientras que el administrador es el unico en manipular un poco mas los datos.

Comment: Si usa el web solo para mirar y hay un solo sistema local, se puede ir guardando los SQL con sus datos y correrlos al volver a conectar. Si no habría que sentarse con el cliente y explicarle todos los problemas que trae la actualización en dos lugares, habría que pedirle que tome la decisión de cómo actualizar en cada caso (ej: se borró un producto en la web mientras se le agregaba un movimiento localmente). Luego ver cuál es el costo de desarrollar todo eso y por último preguntarle si no es más económico contratar un servicio de mayor calidad (o a dos proveedores simultáneamente o 4G, etc).

Comment: bueno esto es que en Venezuela este tipo de servicios en ciertos sectores del país es muy malo y no hay mucho que hacer.. digamos que lo convenzo y las condiciones son favorables para aplicar esto.¿ que herramienta, linea de  código o función me podría servir?

Comment: ¿para aplicar qué? Que la web sea de solo lectura o que el cliente conteste qué hacer en cada caso? Si la respuesta es la primera se puede usar https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION si no dependerá de las respuestas.

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias